# ES6 spread element - default value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to set an empty object as a default value if the array I'm passing in is empty. Something like:

```
var obj = { documents: [...question.documents] || [{}] }
```

I fixed it using a condition, but I want to know if there is a better way to achieve that.

```
if(obj.documents.length === 0) obj.documents.push({})
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a speed operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508

Answer (score 1):

Since even empty arrays are truthy, I don't think there's any great elegant solution other than putting an explicit test in there somewhere. Ternaries are more terse than `if` statements, though:

```js
const question = { documents: [] };
const { documents } = question;
const obj = { documents: documents.length !== 0 ? documents : [{}]}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Here's another possibility:

```js
const question = { documents: [] };
const [firstElm = {}, ...otherElms] = question.documents;
const obj = { documents: [firstElm, ...otherElms] };
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to write this in a single expression

Using the ternary operator:

```
var obj = { documents: [
  ...question.documents.length
    ? question.documents
    : [{}]
  ] 
};
```

Using a default value

```
var obj = { documents: [question.documents[0] || {}, ...question.documents.slice(1)] };
```

In both cases there's some awkwardness stemming from having to refer to the source multiple times

Comment: The second duplicates the first item in the array while spreading: https://jsfiddle.net/ks17peb2/

Comment: @CertainPerformance great catch thank you. I totally forgot by the time I was halfway through. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

> The spread operator is used inside an empty array. I don't see the
>   point in using the spread operator here. The objective can be achieved
>   by using the following.

```
var obj = { documents: question.documents.length ? question.documents : [{}]}
```

If the method you have provided is being used, you don't need an `or` clause, because an empty array also returns a truthy value. So it can be written as the following :-

```
var obj = { documents: question.documents }
if(!obj.documents.length) obj.documents.push({})
```

Answer (score 0):

this should suit...

```js
const question = {
  documents: [],
};

const obj = { 
  documents: [].concat(question.documents.length ? question.documents : {}) 
};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way

```js
const  obj1 ={...(true&& {x:1})};
console.log(obj1)
const  obj2 ={...(false&& {y:1})};
console.log(obj2)
```